# Google Cloud API expired

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I am working on a mobile app project with Kotlin and I implemented auth with google. Everything was fine until I recently bought a Firebase license and I restarted the google APIs which throws this error:

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [API key expired. Please renew the API key. ].

I tried to generate another key and download the .json file and replace it with the old one. But it's not working.

Comment: Can you paste the pattern of the API call that you perform (with header and query param that you set, obfuscate if there is sensible data! Just the pattern is enough)

Comment: Could you please paste the code of how you are calling the API as @guillaume is asking? If the code is working fine, try checking if the error could be a billing concern. You may always contact the [Firebase Team](https://firebase.google.com/support) for further assistance and guidance.